# Can my employer mandate that I increase my car insurance?

Tags: company-policy, compensation

I work as a case manager for children in foster care, and transporting these children is part of my job.

My employer wants me to increase my car insurance to do the job.  No compensation has been offered for me to pay more money out my pocket to continue to do my job.

Can employers make such requirements without compensation?

Comment: Since they are trying to protect the peopel riding with you I see no problem here. It is just a minumum requirement for the job. If you don't like it, vote with your feet.

Comment: Is this a change in working conditions? In other words, are you new in the job, and only just discovering that you need this extra insurance? Or has your employer only just started asking you to use your own car for work?

Comment: I have edited the question and replaced the unethical with a less abstract question. Please feel free to roll back. And I suggest you edit the question anyway, especially your last sentence is very unclear. Also, tell us if this your private car, and whatagreements you have/had.

Comment: Car insurance and related policies vary from company to company and from country to country. Can you narrow your question down a bit?

Comment: It is actually not for a specific position. It can relate to anybody who is asked by their employer to use their vehicle for business including sales people, pizza delivery, administrative assistants.

Comment: The question has been generalized better... But i am unwilling to vote to reopen yet because the question still makes it seem like the increase may be optional.  Is the OP's manager suggesting that the OP needs more insurance to protect the OP in case of an accident where they are transporting children, or is the OP being told that they will be terminated unless they increase their insurance to at least X amount?

Answer (score 9):

State governments set minimum amounts of insurance coverage by law for all licensed drivers.

I know the Boy Scouts of America sets minimum coverage levels for leaders or parents who will be transporting youth to events.

If you will be transporting children in your personally owned vehicle (POV) I would expect that the state agency specifies minimum levels. These levels should be spelled out in regulations. And should have been made clear when you started in your current position. It is also possible that they were recently adjusted.

I would ask if your insurance is considered primary or secondary.

I would also research what your auto insurance company requires when using your POV for work. Is that extra coverage? Do they not cover you if the mileage dedicated to work is greater than X percent of your annual mileage?

Comment: The last paragraph is very important.  Many personal auto policies have exclusions for using your vehicle for work purposes.  Speak with your insurance agent.  In fact, show him the policy letter.

Answer (score 8):

When I worked for a large company if we wanted to use our personal vehicles for company work, we had to have a minimum liability coverage and we were reimbursed so much a mile. If we didn't have that coverage then we could take cabs or whatever and be reimbursed what we spent.

If it's a condition of employment that you provide the car, you can infer that having a valid drivers license and enough insurance are also conditions of employment. The cents-per-mile they are giving you should cover gas, maintenance, wear and tear and insurance for the vehicle. (My experience is that most mileage allowances more than cover all these costs.) If it doesn't, or if you are not given cents-per-mile, address that, but don't try not having enough insurance. That is a very scary path to be going down.